# Enable Cross-Origin cookies without HTTPS

Tags: reactjs, https, nestjs, session-cookies

I'm working on an app that has a Nest.js API, and two React.js frontends (one for backoffice). The API is deployed to an AWS EC2 instance, and both frontends are deployed to AWS S3. The app uses a session to authenticate the user, but both sites are in a different origin than the API. Due to this, I have to use sameSite: 'none'. But due to recent changes in Google Chrome, cookies with sameSite: 'none' are blocked unless secure is true. We need to show an early version of the project to our client, we can't make the site HTTPS right now. Is there a way to get around this restriction?

Comment: Is it the backend or the front that doesn't have HTTPS?

Comment: @jimmy both need to be HTTPS as far as I know. We managed to add HTTPS to the front end with AWS Cloudfront, but we couldn't make it work for the Backend. Cookies don't work with self-signed certificates, so we had to delay our delivery until the client provided us with a secure HTTPS domain. These restrictions are extremely annoying during development.